# Need expression function vb/jscript

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, vbscript

How to display some information on the label, as an example of the attribute "32710100010080123" too long.

I just want to show four last number to "0123", help me to make vbscript expression label.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to add a new field for that. Simply do right([columnName],4) in your label expression builder.

Comment: True. This is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field and use the field calculator to populate it: right(attribute,4) or right([attribute],4) depending on if the featureclass is in a personal or file geodatabase or shapefile.